# Cannot open display on RHEL

Tags: linux, firefox, x11, redhat

I am trying to ssh to a server (myserver) installed with RHEL 5.8 from a desktop client (mydesktop) with RHEL 6.2. I have group installed the "X Window" on the remote server, the DISPLAY variable on the remote server is also set to be localhost:0.0, but I still cannot get firefox started. The command to connect is

```
$ ssh -X -l myname myserver
```

The error message is

```
$ firefox
Error: cannot open display: localhost:0.0
```

I tried to execute the command on myserver below

```
$ xhost +localhost
```

but it gives me an error message

```
xhost:  unable to open display "localhost:0.0"
```

There are three phenomena I want to mention

1. another user of mydesktop is able to start firefox after logging into myserver.
2. I was able to start firefox when I remotely logged into another server: myserver2.
3. firefox is just an example. In general, I cannot launch any x window programs.

I have no idea what is going on. Please help me.

---

This is an update of my problem. The problem was solved "partially". What I did was to delete the "export DISPLAY==localhost:0.0" from my ".bashrc" file, logout and then login again and I can start firefox!!!

---

However, this is not the end of the story. I have a new problem:
$ sudo wireshark

does not work. Here is the error message:

```
[myself@myserver ~]$ sudo wireshark
debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype x11 rchan 2 win 65536 max 16384
debug1: client_request_x11: request from 127.0.0.1 46595
debug1: channel 1: new [x11]
debug1: confirm x11
debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype x11 rchan 3 win 65536 max 16384
debug1: client_request_x11: request from 127.0.0.1 46596
debug1: channel 2: new [x11]
debug1: confirm x11
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
debug1: channel 2: free: x11, nchannels 3
The application 'wireshark' lost its connection to the display localhost:10.0;
most likely the X server was shut down or you killed/destroyed
the application.
debug1: channel 1: FORCE input drain
```

Why can't I start x window under sudo?

Comment: Can you post the output of ssh when used with "-v"? [Verbose mode.  Causes ssh to print debugging messages ...]

Comment: Posted. New problem rises. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

The problem is solved by doing the following two things:

1. commenting out the `export DISPLAY=Localhost:10.0` from my .bashrc file. I think this is because I overwrites the default value of `DISPLAY` environmental variable. By doing this, I am able to start 'firefox' under my regular account.
2. logout, login and add `export XAUTHORITY='/home/myself/.xauthority` into my .bashrc file. Then logout and login again so that I can run `sudo wireshark`.

The `-v` option in the ssh command is very useful when diagnosing the problem.

Comment: The first thing I had to do was as the normal user, do `xhost +localhost` or whatever my host's name is. Then, once I did `sudo su -`, I had to do your step 2, typing in `export XAUTHORITY=/home/myself/.Xauthority` (note the capital X).